# Is this monitor Dell p1913 suitable for coding as the second monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors

Is this monitor Dell p1913 suitable for coding as the second monitor?

It has 1440x900 high resolution.

I already have an Acer monitor 27",

I was looking for the second monitor for practising coding in Python for online courses on statistics?

Could anyone give me an advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is suitable as a second monitor. Not as primary monitor though since the resolution is too low.